# How to fix error when trying to use batch_norm function from lasagne library?

Tags: python, python-3.x, error-handling, lasagne

When i try to use batch_norm function from `lasagne` library:

```
lasagne.layers.batch_norm(...
```

this error appears:

```
AttributeError: module 'lasagne.layers' has no attribute 'batch_norm'
```

However I did all installs and updates which are necessary for that library. How to fix it?

Comment: did you try: `from lasagne.layers import batch_norm`?